# Spyder 4.0.1 dataframe preview

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Updated to Spyder 4.0.1 but it is not possible to open the content of a dataframe. I.e. it is not possible to see the values when double-clicking on the df name in the variable explorer. This was still possible in version 3.3.6. I ran the exact same code so there is nothing wrong with the df itself. Does anyone know how to view the df contents?

Comment: Does closing `spyder` and reopening that solve the issue? I faced a similar issue with an older version and simply restarting `spyder` solved that.

Comment: Restarting Spyder from the Windows console instead of Anaconda solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: You probably installed Pandas after Spyder was started.